# Can you extract the estimatedDepthData and segmentationBuffer when using people occlusion in ARKit

Tags: ios, arkit, image-segmentation

Has anyone successfully extracted the estimatedDepthData and segmentationBuffer from an ARKit application? I am trying to identify any collisions between a person and a rendered asset. As there already exists a segmentation mask and a depth mask during runtime since people occlusion is on, I am wondering if I can get that array and use it to identify collision events.

I've done a bit of research and it seems like I might need to set-up a custom renderer to handle that, but I was wondering if anyone else has had figured out an easier way. I am using a very straightforward configuration.

```
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
    configuration.frameSemantics.insert(.personSegmentationWithDepth)
    // Run the view's session
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both segmentation and depth data are accessible through the properties of the `ARFrame`. You will need to confirm to the `ARSessionDelegate` protocol in order to get updates.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
   if let segmentationData = frame.segmentationBuffer {
       // Do smth with segmentation data
   }
   if let depthData = frame.estimatedDepthData {
       // Do smth with depth data
   } 
}
```